# How to capture the ip for the particular table/ stored procedure access in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Now i have a problem, My team forgot the remote server ip which is hosting the windows services, which we need to stop that services now. We have the access to my sql, and we know which stored procedure and table to be called. However , we need that ip which call to that table / stored procedure? May i know how i can retrieve that ip?

From the google, i only can find this solution

```
select host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

However the result is not like what we expected. May i know is there is another solution?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly? How is an IP address related to a specific table or stored procedure?

Comment: i want to know which ip call that table / stored procedure

Comment: so i can know which server is hosting that program to execute that

Comment: I assume every server has it OWN username en hostname like username@10.0.0.4 or did you wildcard the hostname when creating the users?